# R (sp, sf) how to call an entire row from an irregular grid

Tags: r, sf

I have

```
library(world) 
library(ggplot)
library(sf)

world_coords<-map_data("world")
afghan<-world_coordinates[which(world_coordinates$region=="Afghanistan"),]
afghanshape<-st_polygon(list(cbind(afghan$long,afghan$lat)))
grid_spacing<-st_area(afghanshape)/100
 gridy<- st_make_grid(afghanshape,square=T,cellsize = c(grid_spacing,grid_spacing))%>%st_sf()
  inners<-as.matrix(st_contains(afghanshape,gridy))
  indices_inners<-which(inners==TRUE)
```

which gives the outputs

```
plot(afghanshape)
```

[image]

```
plot(gridy[indices_inners,],add=T)
```

[image]

and I'd like to be able to call on each row in the grid in order to get its bounding box using `st_bbox` so that I may then integrate over these rectangular regions as an approximation for the area of the area of Afghanistan. How do I do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use centroid data for this purpose:

```
gridy=gridy[indices_inners,]

centroids<-st_coordinates(st_centroid(gridy))
centroids <- round(centroids,3)
unique_y<-unique(centroids[,2])


colors_<-sample(colors(),length(unique_y))

plot(gridy,col=NA, border=NA)
for (i in 1:length(unique_y)){
  plot(gridy[centroids[,2] %in% unique_y[i],],col=colors_[i],add=TRUE)
}
```

I rounded the centroid y coordinate in order to avoid issues by approximation

[image]

Then you can use `gridy[centroids[,2] %in% unique_y[nrow],]` for selecting the row from bottom to top.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much